# Create new table and put two lists into an Access Database C#

Tags: c#, database, list, ms-access

I have two lists I would like to put into a new table. The values should correspond with each other in the order that they are in. One list is a string list and the other is an integer list, the new table should have a unique ID field and then have the corresponding string and time. Here is how I am creating the lists so far:

```
public class PaceCalculator
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public double Seconds { get; set; }
    public float EventTimeFloat {get; set;}
    public int Distance {get; set;}
    public float Pace {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Namelist { get; set; }
    public List<int> Distancelist { get; set; }

    public List<int> PaceCalc(List<int> Dlist, List<int> Slist)
    {
        return Slist.Zip(Dlist, (a, b) => a / b).ToList();
    }

    public List<string> NameGain()
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\TriHard.accdb";
        string SelectQuery = "SELECT Time.AthleteID, Athlete.AthleteName, Time.EventTime, Event.EventDistance, Event.EventDate FROM Event INNER JOIN (Athlete INNER JOIN [Time] ON Athlete.[AthleteID] = Time.[AthleteID]) ON Event.[EventID] = Time.[EventID] ORDER BY Event.EventDate DESC;";
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(SelectQuery, Connection);
        Command.Connection.Open();

        OleDbDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        PaceCalculator namepace = new PaceCalculator();

        List<string> Namelist = new List<string>();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            namepace = new PaceCalculator();
            namepace.Name = (string)Reader["AthleteName"];
            string NameAdd = Convert.ToString(namepace.Name);
            Namelist.Add(NameAdd);
        }
        return Namelist;
    }


    public List<int> PaceGain()
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\TriHard.accdb";
        string SelectQuery = "SELECT Time.AthleteID, Athlete.AthleteName, Time.EventTime, Event.EventDistance, Event.EventDate FROM Event INNER JOIN (Athlete INNER JOIN [Time] ON Athlete.[AthleteID] = Time.[AthleteID]) ON Event.[EventID] = Time.[EventID] ORDER BY Event.EventDate DESC;";
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(SelectQuery, Connection);
        Command.Connection.Open();

        OleDbDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        PaceCalculator pace = new PaceCalculator();

        List<int> Distancelist = new List<int>();
        List<int> Secondslist = new List<int>();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            pace = new PaceCalculator();
            pace.Distance = (int)Reader["EventDistance"];
            int DistanceInt = Convert.ToInt32(pace.Distance);
            Distancelist.Add(DistanceInt);

            pace = new PaceCalculator();
            pace.Time = (string)Reader["EventTime"]; //Reads in EventTime
            double Seconds = TimeSpan.Parse(pace.Time).TotalSeconds; //Converts the string into HH:MM:SS as a double
            int SecondsInt = Convert.ToInt32(Seconds); //Converts the double into an integer, returning the seconds in the total time
            Secondslist.Add(SecondsInt); //Adds the Seconds for each time to the list;


        }
        Command.Connection.Close();
        var Pacelist = PaceCalc(Distancelist, Secondslist);
        return Pacelist;

    }
}
```

So the lists I want to add to the new table will be Namelist and Pacelist.
How can I create a new table and put these two lists plus a unique ID field in too?

Comment: Side note: do not forget to *close* all the `IDisposable`'s; the best practice is to put them into `using' i.e. `using (OleDbConnection Connection = new ...) { ...}`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/704743/how-to-create-a-table-in-ms-access-by-csharp). It shows step by step how to do this

As for adding the list to a field, you just need to convert de list to a string like this

```
string stingToInsert = string.Join(" ", NameList.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt show how I would put a list as a field. How can I do this?

Comment: You want the list to be inserted as 1 field ?

Comment: yes, I would like the fields created to be populated with the lists I have created